# When a date is selected in a datepicker it should not accept a birthday which is equal to an age that is higher than 20

Tags: jquery, validation, date

I have this in my html for the datepicker:

```
<div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-xs-4 control-label">Birthday:</label>
       <input type="text" id="dependents-birthday" class="form-control datepicker" />
</div>
```

**This one to set the datepicker:**

```
$("#dependents-birthday").datepicker();
```

When a date is selected in the datepicker it should not accept a date which is equivalent to an age higher than 20. If the selected date is equivalent to an age higher than 20 a modal will pop up.

Comment: have you tried any validation like `$("#dependents-birthday").blur(..`?

Comment: You know you can [restrict the dates a user can enter](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max) right?

Comment: Should I do this:
`$("#dependents-birthday").datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: '+1M +10D' });`

Comment: **This doesnt work for me:**
`$("#dependents-birthday").datepicker({
                    yearRange: "-20:+0"
                });`

Comment: `$("#dependents-birthday").datepicker({
                    showButtonPanel: true,
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,

                    
                });`
**I did this one but I should not set the yearRange. What I need to do is when the user chooses a date which is beyond last 20 years a modal will pop up. How can I do that? Any help is appreciated. :(**

Comment: @user3332115 have you tried my below answer?

Answer (score 0):

Give a try for this:

```
$(function () {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        showButtonPanel: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
       yearRange: "-50:-20",
    });
});
```